# Excel VBA extracting aria-label value

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the text inside the aria-label attribute but what I have doesn't seem to be working. I'm able to extract href values using the same code so I thought it might also work. Any help would be appreciated.

The URL I used is https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/328932021226229
[image: Screenshot:]

```html
<div class="_3-8z">
  <div>
    <span class="_3ziq">Seller Information</span>
    <div class="clearfix" direction="left">
      <div class="_ohe lfloat">
        <div>
          <a class="img _8o _8t" aria-label="John Smith, View seller profile"
      href="#" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100002935356728&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22marketplace_hovercard%22%2C%22existingThreadID%22%3Anull%2C%22forSaleItemID%22%3A%22328932021226229%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Zsigmond%20Lali%22%7D" 
      modalProps="[object Object]" 
      profileID="100002935356728" resource="[object Object]">
```

```
    Sub Macro2()

marker = 0
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title

    If my_title Like "Marketplace" & "*" Then 'compare to find if the desired web page is already open
        Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
        marker = 1
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

        Dim aNodeList As Object, i As Long
        Set aNodeList = IE.document.querySelectorAll(".img _8o _8t[aria-label]")
        For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 2, 2) = aNodeList.Item(i)
        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: your html provided as snippet doesn't match anything in the URL. Are you sure that is the correct URL?

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet link HTML does not appear in the link, at least as I see it. Also, your CSS selector has the wrong class selector for the shown snippet if you are after the shown `aria-label`.

This

```
._3cgd[aria-label]
```

looks for an element with class name `._3cgd` having an `aria-label` attribute. There isn't one present in your snippet.

I would expect, but cannot properly test for reasons above, that you could use `getAttribute`, failing that split the `.outerHTML` of the target element.

The below is a more generalised selector based on your snippet shown. You may need to adjust for your HTML. The `getAttribute` produced `null` with just your snippet but I am unsure if would behave differently with live page as the syntax is correct. The `outerHTML` splitting returns `John Smith, View seller profile`

```
With IE.document.querySelector("a[class='img _8o _8t'][profileid='100002935356728']")
   Debug.Print .getAttribute("aria-label")
   Debug.Print Split(Split(.outerHTML, "aria-label=" & Chr$(34))(1), Chr$(34))(0)
End With
```

I am only using `querySelector` and targeting with `profileid`, to be more general for all matched class with aria-label:

```
Dim eles As Object, i As Long
Set eles = IE.document.querySelectorAll("a[class='img _8o _8t'][aria-label]")
For i = 0 To eles.Length - 1
    With eles.item(i)
        Debug.Print .getAttribute("aria-label")
        Debug.Print Split(Split(.outerHTML, "aria-label=" & Chr$(34))(1), Chr$(34))(0)
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Thats strange. I added a screenshot under the link to show you the html I have. I did change the name in the link for privacy reasons so I just used John Smith. Is this what you're referring too? Btw the first name for the actual name is Zsigmond.

Also sorry about that I must have put the wrong class by mistake when making this post. img _8o _8t should be the correct class. I edited the change.

I did try both of options you have but I’m still having no luck extracting aria-label.

Comment: What result did you get?